# Godaddy ip canonicalization

Tags: seo, htaccess, godaddy, ip-address, canonical-url

I have tried find solution to this all around Google and here, but no luck so far.

when I try connect to my website by using IP, it will not redirect to the website. Only godaddy's "Coming soon" page.

I have tried all kind of .htaccess codes but, again, no luck so far.
Is this some kind of godaddy's issue or ... ?

the code which I use at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

BTW: .htaccess works and it's located correctly, I have tested that also.

Do you have any idea why this happen ?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting account? If so, then Analog's answer below would apply. In that case, you can add a dedicated IP address as an account option if you need one (adding SSL for example requires one). If it's not a shared account, can you provide some more information as to what type of account it is?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specifically have a dedicated IP address from GoDaddy then you are being hosted on a shared IP address. GoDaddy doesn't give each client a dedicated IP address and instead uses IP addresses that are shared to host multiple client sites on a single address.

Because of this if you try and view one of these shared addresses in your browser you will just see the Godaddy holding page.